# How to retrieve data for a statistics page using MYSQL Queries

Tags: mysql, sum

I have a table named tblMatches containing match results of a sporting event.  The score for the winning player is always stored in the P1_Score field, the P2_Score tracks the losing player score.

There are 4 fields within the table that I need to reference.

(P1_ID), (P1_Score), (P2_ID), (P2_Score)

I am passing through an ID_value.  I have managed to calculated the total match wins vs total match losses using a mysql_num_rows function.

I am now trying to calculate the total number of games won vs the total number of games lost.  I need to somehow determine the sum of the scores.

Comment: What's the difference between a match and a game?

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23: game is a part of a match. For example in tennis you need to win 3 games to win a match

Comment: Yes..that is right.  Win enough games to win the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(P1_Score) FROM tbl WHERE P1_ID = $id) won,
       (SELECT SUM(P2_Score) FROM tbl WHERE P2_ID = $id) lost
```

replace `$id` with particular player's id and you'll get how much games he won and lost accordingly